# Issues facing working with GZip

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gzip

I am facing a problem while trying to use GZip .
I have used the below entries in my config files i.e., applicationHost.config and web.config

```
<httpCompression>
  <staticTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />        
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
  </staticTypes>
  <dynamicTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />        
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
  </dynamicTypes>
  <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" dynamicCompressionLevel="4" />
</httpCompression>
<urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true"/>
```

I have my application being deployed on IIS 7.5.
I have seen these suggestions over the net and I happen to hear that I would not need an exclusive stream code to be written. An entry to config file would suffice.
But still I get an error when my WCF service returns me a collection object with records over 1000. The object is a serializable object.
Please help me in this issue

Comment: What error does WCF give you?

Comment: It gives me an exception - The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly
My stack trace reads this..

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)

Comment: Can anyone please help on this.